# UITableViewRowAnimationTop doesn't finish animation

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

I've a problem using UITableViewRowAnimationTop when I insert rows in a tableview. If the inserted cell in the UITableView is bigger than 100 px high then the animation doesn't work properly.

I.e. if you insert a cell with height 200 px then it will instantly show 100 px of the cell and then animate the remaining 100 px of the cell.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is really strange. I recommend using a framework such as the free Sensible TableView and have it handle all these operations automatically.